# Folder junction/link to a OneDrive/SP folder that retains OneDrive features?

Tags: onedrive, sharepoint

We have a request to change the location of OneDrive/SP synced files to the c:\ root folder.

However, this would require the change of all OneDrive folders (personal synced folders, SP libraries, etc).

The command 'mklink /j "c:\example" "c:\users\name\OneDrive"' would do it but c:\example would not retain OneDrive features. (share, view online, etc).

A simple shortcut would also not do it for various reasons (linking to elements inside of the OneDrive folder would not be retained)

Any other ways of doing this?

We do not want to change the default OneDrive folder since this may be overkill for this type of request.

Comment: OneDrive can't change the sync location for a specific file.

Comment: Yes I know - OneDrive entire default folder has to be changed.  I am asking if I can do a pointer to the OneDrive folder and keep the ONeDrive features within that folder (like a shortcut )